# how can I build a regex for validating smtp error codes

Tags: regex, smtp

I'm trying to build a regex for reading and identify smtp error codes in bounced emails, so later I can match this codes with smtp error codes databases and translate with another friendly messages.

The body response from bounced email look like this (only diagnostic code line is relevant):

```
- Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does...
- Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 553 5.1.2 Unknown mail server. Could not find a mail server...
- Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.5.0 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable...
- Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.5.0 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable...
- Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist...
```

It can be two cases:

```
1. 550 5.5.0 -->  3 digit number + space + 3 digit number only if followed by a dot.
2. 550-5.1.1 --> 3 digit number + hyphen + 3 digit number only if followed by a dot.
```

I tried with this regex but not captures first 3 digits and the second 3 digits followed by a dot

```regex
(?<!\d)(\d+\.){2}(?>\d)
```

[image: Regex101.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, this regex should do what you want:

```
(?<=smtp;) ?(\d{3})[ -]((?:\d+\.){2}\d+)
```

It looks for the string `smtp;` followed by an optional space, then 3 digits (captured in group 1), a space or hyphen, and then a string of digits, `.`, digits, `.`, digits (captured in group 2).

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/S64tjY/2)